# Injecting EJB 3 session beans into struts 2 action classes

Tags: java, struts2, ejb-3.0

Is there a way to inject EJB 3 stateless session beans into struts 2 action classes. Please dont suggest a JNDI look up. I want inversion of control.

It would be nice if some one gives me links to illustrations. Ofcourse, I will give you a up vote :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an Example using Guice:

http://www.tzavellas.com/techblog/2007/07/03/using-dependency-injection-in-struts2-for-stateless-ejbs-part-1/

Also this:

http://old.nabble.com/EJb-3.1-(dependency-injection)-and-Struts2-actions-¿CDI-Weld-needed--td26684100.html